# Heavy file copy to linux

Tags: linux, unix

I want to copy a a heavy setup file(Binaries of a software) 3.4 GB from windows to Linux machine.
But I am scared as I dont know if I will copy the file under /home drive it may get full, and space issues can occur, I checked the space using below command :

```
root@tsscpl22dev ~ # du -h /home
8.0K    /home
```

Could anyone please help and let me know how can I check the space and copy it to the right directory.

Comment: Result of :
 df -h /home
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ROOTVG-rootlv
                      5.0G  3.7G  1.1G  79% /

It is showing 1.1G available that means I cant use it right?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `du`, use `df` instead.  `df -h` will show you human-readable figures for the capacity and used/free space of every mounted volume.  If you have no separate `/home` volume then the `/` volume is likely to be where your files under `/home` are stored.

Comment: Result of :
 df -h /home
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ROOTVG-rootlv
                      5.0G  3.7G  1.1G  79% /

It is showing 1.1G available that means I cant use it right?

Comment: Could you suggest me some other path other than /home that I can check, sorry but I am new to Linux

Comment: @Richa run `df` (without arguments)  and see where you can put the file.

Comment: Thanks Renan,Below is the one that shows the maximum space available, 19G so that means I can copy a file of 4GB right? i ran df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/APPVG-hp   20G  173M   19G   1% /opt/HP

Comment: @Richa Correct. `/` has no room for the file(s), but `/opt/HP` does.

Comment: Thank u for your help guys! so I will copy my file under /opt/HP

Comment: So, I will create a new directory under /opt/HP, lets say /opt/HP/bits, can i assign some size to this directory,if yes can u tell how can i assign 8GB to this directory (G is GB in linux right)?

Comment: @Richa If you are asking how to enforce a quota, that will depend on your host Linux distribution as well as possibly on the kernel modules you have available.  You don't usually "assign" space to a directory, just create the directory and it will share free space with all other directories in the same volume.

Answer (score 2):

`du` is not what you want. From the manpage:

```
NAME
    du - estimate file space usage
```

You want `df -h /home`. Even if your `/home` isn't in a separate partition, it should work.

Or better, just use `df` to see all the file systems that are available and choose one that has enough space.

Answer (score 1):

Using `du -sh /home` would be fine.

Comment: Result of :
 df -h /home
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ROOTVG-rootlv
                      5.0G  3.7G  1.1G  79% /

It is showing 1.1G available that means I cant use it right?

Comment: Right. And as @cdhowie said, `df` or `df -h` will display a list of  every mounted volume, you may choose one from the list which have enough space left.